# threading module's reference not removed by gc

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I found `gc` doesn't remove the objects created from `Threading.thread()`.

```
# print memory status every 5sec
def trace_memory():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print(mem_top())

# just print and end
def test_thread():
    print('thread')

threading.Thread(target=trace_memory).start()

curr_count = 0
max_count = 10000
while max_count > curr_count:
    threading.Thread(target=test_thread).start()
    curr_count += 1
```

and below is result of `mem_top()`:

```
refs:
10001   <class 'list'> [<unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x00000204DD680030>, <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x00000204DD

bytes:
90120    [<unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x00000204DD680030>, <unlocked _thread.lock object at 0x00000204DD
```

I created 10000 (`test_thread()`) + 1 (`trace_memory()`) threads and all of `test_thread()` were finished.

But refs:, bytes: show that threads are still referenced by something.

How can I make `gc` to remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the threads at the end:

```py
import threading, time, mem_top, gc


def trace_memory():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print(mem_top.mem_top())

# just print and end
def test_thread():
    print('thread')


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=trace_memory).start()

    curr_count = 0
    max_count = 1000
    threads = []
    while max_count > curr_count:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=test_thread)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        curr_count += 1

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


main()
```